# A class with both normal and static interfaces

Tags: php, class

I need a class that would let the user take advantage of both normal (non-static) methods and static methods. The actual implementation would reside in the static methods, which would be called by virtual non-static methods of the same name via the magic `__call` method. The problem however is that, when calling a non-static method in this way, PHP thinks that the programmer made a mistake and the static method was actually meant to be called:

```
class AClass
{
    public static function method ()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public function __call ($name, $arguments)
    {
        var_dump("Hello");
        call_user_func_array("AClass::$name", $arguments);
    }
}

$obj = new AClass;
$obj->method();
```

So "Hello" is no being output when invoking `method` method on the object but is being output if trying to invoke a method with any other name. Any way to achieve the correct behavior while preserving method naming?

Comment: This is bad design. Call static methods statically, and instance methods referring to every single instance, w/out messing up the two things.

Comment: Yes typically __call is a way to do some operations and used within the instance. For example I have User class which I instantiate with field info from DB and I call $do_user->view() where its not defined anywhere I would use __call() to implement the view() the form !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see why you would try to do that but this seems to work :

```
class AClass
{
    protected static function method ()
    {
        echo "method()\n";
    }

    public function __call ($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo("Hello normal\n");
        call_user_func_array("self::$name", $arguments);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo("Hello static\n");
        call_user_func_array("self::$name", $arguments);
    }
}

$obj = new AClass;

// Normal call
$obj->method();

// Static call
AClass::method();
```

Output :

```
Hello normal
method()
Hello static
method()
```

The thing is, accordingly to its documentation, the __call method is only used if a function is inaccessible from the context you called it from.

So since in your case the function was public, there was no need to use it (even if with some settings it displays a warning).

If you make it "protected" or "private", it can't be called from the outside and then __call is used.

Because __call doesn't care about static calls, you also have to use __callStatic (available in PHP >=5.3) if you still need to call AClass::method from outside your class.

Comment: Ya, I thought of it too, just wanted to minimize the number of `call_user_func_array` for better performance